# Get character index on right click for CodeArea

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I am using `CodeArea` from `RichTextFX` in my code editor. I need to show context menu on right click and fill it based on the text where mouse is pointing. Like if I right click a function call, there will be "Go to declaration" in the context menu.
To do that I need to get character index where the mouse is pointing. For `MouseOverTextEvent` there is the `getCharacterIndex()` method, but there is no such method in `ContextMenuEvent` or `MouseEvent`.

Saving the last index from `MouseOverTextEvent` is not a good option for me because I use `MouseOverTextEvent` for showing popup messages and this event has a 1 second delay (used `setMouseOverTextDelay`).

How can I get the character index for this right click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`hit(...)`](http://fxmisc.github.io/richtext/javadoc/0.10.5/org/fxmisc/richtext/GenericStyledArea.html#hit-double-double-) method inherited from `GenericStyledArea` gives you access to the index of the closest character, given the `x` and `y` coordinates in the code area's coordinate system (which you can readily get from the mouse event).